# Ubuntu One Authentication process

Tags: ubuntu-one, authentication, single-sign-on

I went to sign up for Ubuntu One and during the sign up process, I had to wait for the authentication code before I could proceed. I thought this was an instant process and it took a while for the email to come. So I exited the program and now I cant find where to enter in the authentication code at or how to bring it back up. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you closed the desktop client before receiving the email verification token, you might be able to complete the validation via the web.

In the email, there should be a unique token string that I will refer to as $TOKEN here.  Open your web browser and point it at:

```
https://login.ubuntu.com/token/$TOKEN/
```

Follow the prompts and it should validate your account.  Once that is done, try logging in with the desktop client again and say you have an existing account.